# C++ converting binary string to decimal string

Tags: c++, binary, numbers

I have a binary string that is potentially greater than 64 bits/characters. I would like to convert it into base-10 so that I can output it to the console.

As far as I know, c++ doesn't support any integers greater than 64 bits, with exceptions to compiler specific types. Therefore, I would need to convert the binary string to a base-10 string (as opposed to a base-10 integer) if I want to output it to the console in a human-readable form.

I have the following code...

```cpp
int char_to_int(const char c) {
    return ((int) c) - 48;
}

std::string string_addition(std::string s1, std::string s2) {
    std::string ret = "";
    // making sure the two strings are the same length
    while(s1.size() > s2.size())
        s2 = '0' + s2;
    while (s2.size() > s1.size())
        s1 = '0' + s1;
    
    // adding and carrying
    for (int32_t i = (int32_t) s1.size(); i >= 0; i--)
        ret[i] = (char) ((char_to_int(s1[i]) + char_to_int(s2[i])) + 48);
    for (int32_t i = (int32_t) ret.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        ...
    // then finally returning
    return ret
}

std::string to_base_ten(const std::string& s) {
    std::string ret = "";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        // for each digit, calculate the appropriate number to add
        int64_t temp = s[i] * (int) std::pow(2, i);
        // performing addition with strings because of potential integer overflow issues
        ret = string_addition(ret, std::to_string(temp));
    }

    return ret;
}
```

...which just gets tedious and hard to read/understand because of converting with strings. Are there any simpler or more efficient ways of accomplishing this task?

Comment: Write a function to divide two strings in binary and produce a remainder viz.  `std::string string_divide(std::string s1, std::string s2, std::string &remainder)`   (you will, almost certainly, find that doing a division produces the remainder as a side-effect).    Then repeatedly divide by `"1010"` (the binary representation of decimal 10).

Comment: Short answer: no there are not. There are very, very few magic buttons in C++ that only need to be located, and pushed, in order to accomplish the entire task at hand, and this isn't one of them. P.S. any attempt to use `std::pow()` with two integer values, like the shown code does, is automatically wrong. You might be surprised to learn that, for example, `std::pow(2,2)` may not actually be 4.

Comment: Also,  don't use `std::pow()` (a floating point function) to raise `2` to an integral power.  That introduces rounding/precision errors unnecessarily - and there are easy ways to do that with integer and/or bitwise operations.    And don't hard-code magic values like `48`  (use `'0'`, which represents what is going on, even if using a non-ASCII character set in which `'0'` does not have a numeric value of `48`).

Comment: [bitset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) might help. Imho it's better to use a type other than string to handle arithmetic operation. Also you may consume a chunk of 64bits then process chunk by chunk. It seems like you need to handle arithmetic operation as wel, in that case `std::string` is harder to operate.

Comment: I would probably represent the value in binary as a vector of 32- or 64-bit values. Super easy to convert from binary/hex/octal string, and to perform operations on. Not quite so easy to convert _from_ base 10, but relatively easy to convert _to_ base 10.

Comment: Side note: C++ does support integers over 64 bits, though an implementation might not, because C++ does not specify the upper sizes of integer types beyond each type cannot be larger than the next larger type. `short`, for example cannot be larger than `int`. They can all be the same size, though, and odd as it sounds, I've seen this done.

Comment: You could use [boost multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) to convert a binary string to a decimal string of arbitrary size.  [See this sample](https://godbolt.org/z/EerhvxEh3).  If this is acceptable, then I could post this as an answer.

Comment: [@PaulMcKenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3133316/paulmckenzie) That does seem like a clean way of doing things, and I'll certainly take a look at it. However, I'm fairly new to c++ and am not too keen on using the `boost` library, since i am still getting a grasp of how the language functions under the hood. Hence, for my (very special) case though, I would prefer something that does not use an external library

Comment: *Since i am still getting a grasp of how the language functions under the hood* -- If that is the case, nothing stops you from looking at the boost source code.  The multiprecision type is still "basic" C++, just more complex and put together by very smart people.

Comment: Yes, you'll need a library. bigint might be simpler; however, boost multiprecision is header-only, so it should be easy to get into. If you had to get into the boost build process, that might be intermediate difficulty. Alternatively, I used python for everything I did on project euler, but that doesn't help you learn c++

Comment: @Somedude -- Also, using a library basically ensures that the code you have will work correctly.   You can spend time on trying to get your solution to work, but can you guarantee it doesn't have bugs?  If it does, can you fix them?  Can another programmer tell by looking at your code what it actually does?  Using a library, or at least the code I linked to, it is obvious to any programmer who knows `std::accumulate` they will understand what it does, because of the brevity of the code.  The less code you write, the less bugs will occur.

Comment: @KennyOstrom -- I see that python has available an `mpmath` add-on (I am no python expert), but I know that python has arbitrary precision math built-in.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any simpler or more efficient ways of accomplishing this
> task?

I will post this as an answer to the general query of "converting a binary string to a decimal string".

Assuming that the issue has to do with an arbitrary size decimal, then one solution is to use an arbitrary precision library.  One such library is [boost multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html), most notably the `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int` type.

The following example shows usage of the `cpp_int` type, as well as the `std::accumulate` function to build the decimal string, based on the current binary digit being processed:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>

namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;

std::string to_base_10(std::string binary_digits)
{
    using Int = mp::cpp_int;
    int curPower = 0;
    return std::accumulate(binary_digits.rbegin(), binary_digits.rend(), Int(),
                    [&](Int total, char ch) 
                    { 
                        if ( ch == '1')  // check if digit is 1
                            total += mp::pow(mp::cpp_int(2), curPower); // equivalent to total + 2^curPower                   
                        ++curPower;  // add 1 to the current power 
                        return total;                            
                    }).str(); // convert the final result to a string
}

int main() 
{
    auto s = to_base_10("10001110000011010101010101111000001101010100111000111000111110001110001111111000000011111111110");
    std::cout << s;
}
```

Output:

```
21981495524443696438500395006
```

The `std::accumulate` function will process the string from right-to-left (using the reverse iterators `rbegin` and `rend`), checking to see if the current digit is 1.

If the digit is 1, then then value of 2^current_power is added to the total.  The current power is incremented, and the process is repeated.  The `str()` function is a member of `cpp_int` that converts the final result to a string.

Also note that there is no `string_addition` function.  It is not necessary when building the `cpp_int`, which will eventually be converted to a string at the end of the processing.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any simpler or more efficient ways of accomplishing this task?

I've also solved a similar problem of arithmetic with strings without using libraries other than "string" for the solution. To make it more readable, instead of adding a "humand-readable string", you could instead try adding "computer-readable strings", by this I mean that the character representing '0' should just be 0 instead of the human-readable 48, doing this avoids having to convert char to int and back multiple times...

```
// adding and carrying
for (int32_t i = (int32_t) s1.size(); i >= 0; i--)
    ret[i] = s1[i] + s2[i];
for (int32_t i = (int32_t) ret.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

When having to output the string for humans to read, just make a function that iterates through the string and outputs each character corresponding to the "computer readable string" (you may not need the cast to a char)...

```
void output_number_string(const std::string& s) {
    for (auto l : s)
        std::cout << ((char) (l + '0'));
}
```

Regarding that "std::pow(2, i)", it's also prone to overflowing, to avoid that you should use you overflow-free functions for the task...

```
std::string to_base_ten(const std::string& s) {
    std::string ret = "";
    //initialize two_power to be a string of length one containing only the "computer readable one"
    std::string two_power = string(1, 1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        //in binary, you only need to add a power of two when the bit isn't 0
        if (s[i] == 0) continue;
        // performing addition with strings because of potential integer overflow issues
        ret = string_addition(ret, two_power);
        two_power = string_addition(two_power, two_power);
    }
return ret;
}
```

one extra thing I may have noticed is that the program can't handle the case when the result string is greater than the original strings, but you can just simply insert a '0' at the start of the string after making sure they're the same size:

```
// making sure the two strings are the same length
ret = '0' + ret;
// ...
```

Comment: Very interesting; I'll certainly give that a try. As a side note, what did you mean when the resulting string is greater than the original strings?

Comment: @Somedude
The resulting string will somethimes be greater than both s1 and s2, this happens when the last/most significant digits have to carry to the next digit, for example:
"999" + "1" gets processed to: "999" + "001" and then you proceed to do the addition, "9 + 1 = 0, carry the one" but you end up with "999" + "1" = "000" because there was no digit for the last carry, the string resulting string should have had one extra space for the last carry, hence the "ret = '0' + ret;" to accomodate for the carry

Comment: @Somedude You should also note that with this approach, the resulting numbers tend to have leading 0's than don't convey meaningful information, as a nice challenge for you: make a function that removes leading zeroes and take into account the edge case of the number being "0"